# Calling derived class method from base class destructor

Tags: c++

I have the following snippet of destructor code in base class "SceneNode" that is trying to clear its member vector and delete vector's objects that are derived from SceneNode, but getting an error at **Deleting child->toString** line, can you please point at the right direction:

```
SceneNode::~SceneNode() {

LOG(DEBUG)<< "Node children size: " + to_string(children.size()) + " [" + toString() + "]";

// clean children nodes
for (SceneNode* child : children) {
    LOG(DEBUG) << "Deleting ";
    LOG(DEBUG) << "Deleting " + child->toString();
    delete child;
    LOG(DEBUG) << "Deleted " + child->toString();
}
```

When I debug, it shows me a correct derived object there:

```
    Name : child
Details:0x3204b40
Default:0x3204b40
Decimal:52448064
Hex:0x3204b40
Binary:11001000000100101101000000
Octal:0310045500

Name : lib::SceneNode
Details:{_vptr.SceneNode = 0x4e3430 <vtable for lib::ImageSceneNode+16>, id = {static npos = <optimized out>, _M_dataplus = {<std::allocator<char>> = {<__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<char>> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, _M_p = 0x3204c08 "New Node"}}, position = {x = 0, y = 0}, size = {x = 1920, y = 1080}, center = {x = 960, y = 540}, rotation = 0, alpha = 255, enabled = true, visible = true, deleted = false, parent = 0x22fca0, children = {<std::_Vector_base<lib::SceneNode*, std::allocator<lib::SceneNode*> >> = {_M_impl = {<std::allocator<lib::SceneNode*>> = {<__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<lib::SceneNode*>> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, _M_start = 0x0, _M_finish = 0x0, _M_end_of_storage = 0x0}}, <No data fields>}, animators = {<std::_Vector_base<lib::NodeAnimator*, std::allocator<lib::NodeAnimator*> >> = {_M_impl = {<std::allocator<lib::NodeAnimator*>> = {<__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<lib::NodeAnimator*>> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, _M_start = 0x0, _M_finish = 0x0, _M_end_of_storage = 0x0}}, <No data fields>}, sceneManager = 0x22fc98}
Default:{...}
Decimal:{...}
Hex:{...}
Binary:{...}
Octal:{...}
```

Log:

```
2015-03-09 15:33:39,685 DEBUG [default] [] [virtual lib::SceneNode::~SceneNode()] [..\src\lib\scene\node\SceneNode.cpp:30] Node children size: 1 [SceneNode]

2015-03-09 15:33:39,685 DEBUG [default] [] [virtual lib::SceneNode::~SceneNode()] [..\src\lib\scene\node\SceneNode.cpp:34] Deleting 

2015-03-09 15:33:39,685 FATAL [default] CRASH HANDLED; Application has crashed due to [SIGSEGV] signal
```

Thank you!

Comment: You cannot do this. The derived class has already been destroyed.

Comment: I believe there is a corollary regarding constructors as well (i.e., calling the virtual function of a derived class will not work because the derived class has not been constructed yet).

Comment: Thank you, now if i remove derived methods calls, it fails, I guess this is my original issue, I put crazy logging statements to see what's happening:

Comment: for (SceneNode* child : children) {
  delete child;
 }

Comment: The first call is fine assuming that the pointers in `children` are valid. The problem is the second call, which happens after you already deleted `child`. By that point, there's no object you can call a function on.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, you gave me great hints! All good now: 1) Don't call overridden methods as the object is gone 2) read more about c++ inheritance. Cheers

Comment: @T.C. is correct about the implentation of your `for-loop`. I misread your question and was answering about calling a virtual function of a derived class.

Comment: James, it never reached the stage this line of code, so that could be my next question, original issue is indeed calling overridden toString before doing delete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First change this:

```
LOG(DEBUG) << "Deleting " + child->toString();
```

to this:

```
LOG(DEBUG) << "Deleting " << child->toString();
```

Then remove this line, as at this point that variable has been destroyed and you cannot access it (this is the cause of the crash):

```
LOG(DEBUG) << "Deleted " + child->toString();
```